# Is MPMoviePlayerController capable of playing a small movie really without any kind of overlay?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to play a movie without any overlay from the player. No play/stop buttons, no time line, no start/end time, no progress bar, nothing. Just the plain naked movie in a subview. The movie may then be covered by my own graphics. The documentation does say it's possible to disable controls. However, something like "remaining time" or a progress bar is not neccessarily a "control". Who knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the controlStyle property of the MPMoviePlayerController to MPMovieControlStyleNone and nothing will be displayed except the video.